# Como puedo manipular las respuestas de una encuesta para que el usuario al finalizar pueda enviarlas al backend

Tags: javascript

teniendo un arreglo de preguntas y respuestas. En donde puedo ir almacenando las respuestas de los usuarios, para que al final de la encuesta se envíen a la base de datos?, estaba pensando en guardar las respuestas en el localStorage y al finalizar la encuesta enviarlas mediante una petición ajax por post, pero no se si sea lo mejor. quisiera hacerlo algo asi como el forms office al momento de contestar las encuestas.

[image: Imagen del arreglo de mis preguntas, en este caso solo es una pregunta, pero pueden ser infinitas.]

Comment: de todas fomas tendrás que mandarlo por POST a tu backend, si no lo haces entonces todo queda en el forntend. Si o sí tienes que realizar la petición, ya es cosa tuya de como lo quieras hacer

Comment: entonces recomiendas que vaya enviando las respuestas del usuario de 1 por 1, en lugar de almacenar todas en JavaScript y juntas al finalizar la encuesta?

Comment: como quieras, pero recuerda que hay un límite de lo que puedes enviar por POST :)

Comment: enterado, gracias!!

Comment: Puede influir si quieres que el usuario guarde el avance de la encuesta para que la guardes localmente y la envies al final.  Primero solo haz una prueba con una o dos respuestas asi decidiras que es lo que mas te conviene.

Comment: gracias, voy a probar, igual quiero evitar guardar las respuestas de los usuarios que no finalicen la encuesta